# Where should the missing {} be?

Tags: errors, brackets

When I write down the equation, an error appears that {} is missing:

```
A^{\overline^{\overline{B}}} = C
```

[image]

Latex generates the equation correctly in pdf, but it reports this error.

Error:

```
Missing { inserted. A^{\overline^
Missing } inserted. \end{equation}
```

The full document:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  A^{\overline^{\overline{B}}} = C
   \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Where should the missing {} be and why it generates pdf correctly, but reports an error?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the second `^`.

Comment: Thank you, it works.

Comment: `\overline` should be followed by a single token or a token list enclosed by `{` and `}`. e.g., `\overline A` and `\overline{AB}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\overline` command is TeX primitive with obligatory parameter `math-field`. It can be `{math-mode-material}` or `character` or `math-character`. None of them is `^` (because the `character` must have category code 11 or 12 or it is a `\chardef` token), so `\overline^` is TeX syntax error.

TeX suggests to recover from this error by inserting `{` before `^` as mentioned in the error message:

```
 ! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
^
l.3 $$A^{\overline^
                 {\overline{B}}} = C$$
?
```

so the input stream looks like this (after error recovery):

```
$$A^{\overline{^{\overline{B}}} = C$$
```

but the group opened by inserted `{` isn't closed at the end of math mode, so TeX reports the second error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
<to be read again> 
$
l.3 $$A^{\overline^{\overline{B}}} = C$
                                     $
?
```

Now, the input stream looks like:

```
$$A^{\overline{^{\overline{B}}} = C}$$
```

It is syntactically correct but it isn't definitely what was your intend.

Comment: Thank you very much.